# Unable to get proper output from regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my text which is nothing but HTML tags in string format

```js
var str = "<td class='compl-text> I want </div></td></tr> <td class='compl-text'> to extract </div></td></tr> <td class='compl-text'> this text </div></td></tr>";
var s_txt = str.match(/compl-text\s*(.*?)\s*div/g);

console.log(s_txt);
```

while s_txt gives me output as `compl-text"><div,compl-text"><div,compl-text"><div,compl-text"><div`
but I want the Output to be `I want, to extract, this text`
What changes should be made in order to get this output.

> P.S Here I don't want to use any loop, just want to use just regex.

Thanks.

Comment: Your HTML string is nowhere close to being valid HTML. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes that's being intensional..Its just treated as text

Comment: If you had valid HTML, you could wrap string in parent element and then `el.innerText` to get only text inside tags

Comment: @Justinas the text (html) is fetched as text as only pure text and not as html format.

Comment: @Justinas Yeah, that's where I was going to, but it seems that there's no rhyme or reason to the input string: unbalanced quotes, unbalanced tags, etc. Not even going to bother to write a regex for that. I doubt that anyone will if OP doesn't come up with some rules that the input will obey to.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Oh, I see that it's pure mess in "HTML" string. No way to solve it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is not valid, with valid HTML you could do something like this:

```js
var newEl = $('<div>');
newEl.html("<span>Hi, <b>FRIEND</b>, how are you?</span>");

console.log(newEl.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

But with your invalid string, all you can do is find strings between `>` and `<`

```js
var str = "<td class='compl-text> I want </div></td></tr> <td class='compl-text'> to extract </div></td></tr> <td class='compl-text'> this text </div></td></tr>";

var regex = />([\w ]+)</g;

var s_txt = str.match(regex).filter(function (a) {
  return a != "> <";
}).map(function (a) {
  return a.replace(/>|</g, "")
}).join();

console.log(s_txt);
```